# How to speed up sequential binary writes in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to speed up a Python function which is responsible for writing an extremely large amount of binary data. At the moment, there are a bunch of sequential `write` calls which I suspect are slowing down execution. It's not clear to me how to speed this up though, because the data types are not the same between sequential `write` calls. Imagine something like this:

```py
with open("path/to/my/file.bin", "wb+") as f:
    while(True):
        data = data_queue.get()
        f.write(np.array(np.frombuffer(data[10:30], dtype=np.uint16)))
        if data[0] == 0:
            f.write(np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=np.uint8))
            f.write(np.array([3, 4], dtype=np.uint16))
        elif data[0] == 1:
            f.write(np.array([5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=np.uint32))
        ...
        # A bunch of other conditional writes based off of what is in "data"
```

Is there a simple way I can combine these `write` calls, maybe using Pandas or Numpy, to speed up writing to the binary file?

Comment: Perhaps you could concatenate the arrays' bytes outside the `for` loop.  That way, you could reduce it down to a single `f.write`.

Comment: Try increasing the buffer size, e.g., `open('...', "wb+", buffering=1024*1024)`. The default buffer size (see `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`) is probably smaller than it needs to be.

Comment: The number of calls to `f.write` is less important the number of low-level file writes that will flush the buffer to disk.

Comment: It doesn't get much faster if you remove the write -> It is the Python loop and the array creation which are the limiting part. Can you give a bit more information what your input looks like (maybe 4 simple numpy-arrays you just want to store in the format you described? In this case a structured numpy array can help.

Comment: I edited the sample code to give a more representative example. Basically, I'm waiting on a queue to receive data, and I don't know what I'm going to be writing until after I get the data from the queue. So it is difficult to construct a sequence in advance.